# Сообщение в лог

Tags: android

при выгрузки приложения на устройство в logcat вышло сообщение кажется что-то связано с sdk помогите не могу разобраться[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> /? E/ActivityThread: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@41059f58 that was originally bound here
>   android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@41059f58 that was originally bound here
>   at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.(LoadedApk.java:950)
>                                                      at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:844)
>                                                      at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1118)
>                                                      at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:371)
>                                                      at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
>                                                      at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
>                                                      at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
>                                                      at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1778)
>                                                      at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:552)
>                                                      at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:550)
>                                                      at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
>                                                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
>                                                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
>                                                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
>                                                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
>                                                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

Comment: Скорее всего у вас утечка памяти связанная с передачей ссылки на активити в АсинкТаск и последующим поворотом экрана.